# Anylogic pedwait assistance

Tags: anylogic

How do I write a free() function call? and where do I write it? I am trying to create something that I trigger to release all waiting peds in those blocks. I do not know coding and am really struggling with this.

What do I need to write to release all pedestrians from to move on to the next block called "exitpaths" in the screenshot.

[image]

If someone could help me understand how to write the code and where to write it, that would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about how to free all pedestrians from a pedWait block: `waitingaround.freeAll()`.

The answer to your question about when to perform this action: it depends on what your model's logic is. You can basically type this code inside any block. If you are trying to model the pedestrians' behavior when an emergency happens, you need to trigger this action inside that (it may be an `event`, for example).